# Navigation bar not same width as container

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to web dev and this is the first website i'm building.

I've spent a while on the navigation bar, but i can't get the width of the bar to reach the end of the container. I've included a picture to show the problem i'm having.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wSNn.png) The pictures and navbar are both within the container but i'd like both of them to be lined up.

HTML & CSS:

```html
<html>
      <body>
          <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
             <div class="logo"></div>
             <div id="nav">
              <ul>
               <li><a class="active" href="#index">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
               <li><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
               <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
               <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="cover"></div>
        
            </div>
        
        
          </div>
         <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          
          <style type="text/css">
          
          body {
         background-color: #505290  !important;
        }
        
        .header {
         background-image: url(nlbg.jpg);
         background-size: cover;
         background-position: center center;
         height: 10em;
         width: 100%;
        
        }
        
        .logo {
         content: url(nnlogo.png);
         height: 120px;
        }
        
        #nav ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          background-color: #333;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 1.4em;
        }
        
        #nav li {
          font-family: arial, sans-serif;
          font-size: 1.5em;
          line-height: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 19%;
        }
        
        #nav a{
          display: block;
          color: white;
        }
        
        #nav a:hover {
          background-color: #111;
        }
        
        #nav a.active {
          background-color: #black;
          color: #505290;
        }
        
        .cover {
          content: url(cover.jpg);
        
        }
          
          </style>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Margin 0 on ul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a `top`/`left`/`bottom`/`right` margin of `1.4em` on your navbar. If you want to keep the `top`/`bottom` margin, just set it to `margin:1.4em 0;` to zero out the `left`/`right` margin.

```css
body {
    background-color: #505290  !important;
}

.header {
    background-image: url(nlbg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 10em;
    width: 100%;

}

.logo {
    content: url(nnlogo.png);
    height: 120px;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1.4em 0;
}

#nav li {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19%;
}

#nav a{
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

#nav a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

#nav a.active {
  background-color: #black;
  color: #505290;
}

.cover {
  content: url(cover.jpg);

}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="logo"></div>
                    <div id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="active" href="#index">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cover"></div>

                </div>


        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Haha i'm amazed at how simple this was, spent longer than i'd like to admit on this problem as well lol

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are quite welcome! Just remember that by default `unordered lists` will have `margin` applied to them by the browser, so when you are using them for navigation, you'll want to cancel out or override that default margin.

Answer (score -1):

Try adjusting the margin on the `ul`:

```css
body {
  background-color: #505290 !important;
}

.header {
  background-image: url(nlbg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  content: url(nnlogo.png);
  height: 120px;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  /*margin: 1.4em;*/
}

#nav li {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19%;
}

#nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

#nav a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

#nav a.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: #505290;
}

.cover {
  content: url(https://placehold.it/800x800);
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cover"></div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Just removing the margin will make more changes than desired.  Set margin-left to 0 instead, and leave the rest, assuming you actually want margin around the top/bottom/right.

Comment: @Daniel Fair enough, but the answer will make it fairly obvious to the OP what the problem was, and he can fine tune as he wants...

Answer (score -1):

Your `#nav ul` margin of 1.4em is adding margin to the left of your nav ul.  Set margin-left to 0 on that.